# CSS Whitespace Top Margin

Tags: html, css

I have whitespace above a row/container (Im not sure which, probably the container?) that I need gone.  The code is straightforward,

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <blockquote data-wow-delay="0.1s" data-wow-duration="1s" class="about-quote wow fadeInUp">
              <div>
                <h1 id="one">big</h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.                  
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 id="two">willy</h1>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.
            </div>
                          </blockquote>
        </div>
```

Nothing fancy, yet there is constant chunk of whitespace above it separating it from the element above.

I've tried removing it with

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

and by replacing body with container, row and col respectively, but the white space remained and it just messed up the layout.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet? Generally, I use the browser console for issues like this. Most likely it is Bootstrap applying its default styles. Open your console in browser by right-clicking on the element and 'Inspect element' and the browser will show you a beautiful box model - you can also toggle there each rule applied to the style, until you figure out which one is causing it. You can also try to write new rules in there so they update in real time and you see if they have the desired effect. Hope this helps.

Comment: The whitespace is most likely caused by the HTML also.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, it has some default styling (margins and paddings) for elements, for instance the blockquote gets a default padding of 10px on top and the header has also some margins, if you change them, then you can reduce the whitespace on top, but not sure if this is what you meant

Comment: If editing the row is not removing the white space, it might also be due to the element above it.

Comment: Need to know what styles are applied to `about-quote wow fadeInUp` classes, blockquote, ids `one two`, etc. This is a question about layout, it is essential that you provide us with the CSS.